# Can I make an Objective-C method inlined?

Tags: objective-c, methods, inline

We can define an C function as `inline`. But how about Obj-C methods? Can I make a method "inline"ed?

Comment: See also: [Does LLVM convert ObjC methods to inline functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8194504)

Comment: You cannot inline an Objective-C function.  You can inline a standard C function.

Comment: @BenPious Oops, yeah, duplicated. I searched but did not find it, therefore I raised a question by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective C methods cannot ever be inlined, unfortunately.

There are lots of things which can affect which method will be invoked when a message is sent, and it can change at runtime, so inlining just isn't possible. Java has "final" to mitigate this issue but Objective C does not have a direct equivalent. Instead, you can use plain C functions in time-critical situations to dodge the issue.

Answer (score 3):

No, `Objective-C` methods cannot.

`C` functions however, can be.

Objective-c offers a handy `#define` in `coreGraphics.h` so you can use it to adapt something similar

```
#if !defined(CG_INLINE)
# if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#  define CG_INLINE static inline
# elif defined(__cplusplus)
#  define CG_INLINE static inline
# elif defined(__GNUC__)
#  define CG_INLINE static __inline__
# else
#  define CG_INLINE static    
# endif 
#endif
```

so your inline function will look like this:

`CG_INLINE void doWork(...) { }`