# Keeping object on top of keyboard in the event of becomeFirstResponder or resignFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

I currently have a UITextField on top of a keyboard. When you tap it, it should stick on top of the keyboard and move up smoothly. I don't know the exact duration and animation type of the keyboard, so it's really bumpy. Here's what I have:

```
[theTextView resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
// Frame changes go here (move down 216px)
[UIView commitAnimations];

[theTextView becomeFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
// Frame changes go here (move up 216px)
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If anyone has done something like this before, I would like to know the settings you used to make the animation smooth and make it appear that the bar is "stuck" to the top of the keyboard.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

UIKit posts `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` when it shows the keyboard, and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` when it hides the keyboard.  These notifications contain everything you need to properly animate your `UITextField`.

Let's say your `UITextField` is in a property called called `myTextField`.

First, you need to register for the notifications somewhere.  Where you register depends on what object is responsible for moving `myTextField`.  In my project, the field's superview is responsible, and since I load my UI from a nib, I do it in the superview's `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideOrShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideOrShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

If you use a `UIViewController` to move the field around, you'll probably want to do it in `viewWillAppear:animated:`.

You should unregister in your `dealloc` or `viewWillDisappear:animated:`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Of course the tricky bit is in the `keyboardWillHideOrShow:` method.  First I extract the animation parameters from the notification:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHideOrShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

The `keyboardFrame` is in the global coordinate system.  I need to convert the frame to the same coordinate system as `myTextField.frame`, and `myTextField.frame` is in the coordinate system of `myTextField.superview`:

```
    CGRect keyboardFrameForTextField = [self.myTextField.superview convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];
```

Next, I compute the frame that I want `myTextField` to move to.  The bottom edge of the new frame should be equal to the top edge of the keyboard's frame:

```
    CGRect newTextFieldFrame = self.myTextField.frame;
    newTextFieldFrame.origin.y = keyboardFrameForTextField.origin.y - newTextFieldFrame.size.height;
```

Finally, I animate `myTextField` to its new frame, using the same animation parameters that the keyboard is using:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.myTextField.frame = newTextFieldFrame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Here it is all put together:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHideOrShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrameForTextField = [self.myTextField.superview convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];

    CGRect newTextFieldFrame = self.myTextField.frame;
    newTextFieldFrame.origin.y = keyboardFrameForTextField.origin.y - newTextFieldFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.myTextField.frame = newTextFieldFrame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. With a little modification, I have it working and it's looking super slick.

Comment: @rob mayoff the problem is when I've a `UITabBar`. When the keyboard will hide the `UITextField` slides down under the `UITabBar`. Why?

Comment: If you have a tab bar, then when the keyboard is hiding you need to compute `newTextFieldFrame` based on the frame of the tab bar instead of the frame of the keyboard.

Comment: Or you can save `self.myTextField.frame` when the keyboard shows, and restore it when the keyboard hides.

Comment: I can recommend doing the observer notifications in `- viewDidAppear:` and again remove the observer in `- viewDidDisappear:`. You could be surprised by undefined behavior if you are presenting a keyboard in a sub view controller.

Comment: The UIViewAnimationCurve value can't be passed directly to options; they're different types. You need to convert it first or your timing will be slightly off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327249/ios-how-to-convert-uiviewanimationcurve-to-uiviewanimationoptions

Comment: A small pedantic correction: it should be integerValue instead of intValue.

Comment: this works very nicely when an inputAccessoryView does not fit the bill!

Comment: Won't constraints to UITextView, that is already in IB break this nice little trick?

Answer (score 5):

Set your text field (or a view holding the text field) as the `inputAccessoryView` of the field that you are editing. It will then automatically be attached to the top of the keyboard and animate appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make the UITextField to dock to keyboard (with animation), you need to do offset calculations and apply offset changes on  the scroll view (assuming UITextField is placed in UIScrollView) using `setContentOffset:animation:` method.

Comment: It's not in the ScrollView. A scrollView doesn't even exist, it's a UITableView.

Comment: @phpnerd211: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your keyboard notification:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: Notification) {
    let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size.height ?? 216
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double ?? 0.25
    let curve = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt ?? 7) << 16
    tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - submitButtonContainer.frame.size.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve)], animations: {
        // Animation
    }, completion: nil)
}
```