# Synchronously slide up UIView and resize UITableView when UITextField is fired

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I would to resize a `UITableView` and slide up a `UIView` that contains a `UITextField` when this field is fired. These are two simple mockups:

[image]
[image]

Now I have this code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y - 167, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height)]; // 216 (keyboard's height) - 49 (tabbar's height) = 167

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y + 167, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return TRUE;
}
```

The problem is that the keyboard slide up animation and the `myView` slide up animation are not synchronous. How to make these two animation perfectly synchronous?

And how to resize the `UITableView` when the keyboard is visible and return to the original height when keyboard will hide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping object on top of keyboard in the event of becomeFirstResponder or resignFirstResponder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704137/keeping-object-on-top-of-keyboard-in-the-event-of-becomefirstresponder-or-resign)

Comment: How about using the UIView you display on the bottom as a tableFooterView. If all of this now is wrapped into a UITableViewController, you get the functionality you want for free.

Comment: @till no because I want the UIView is always visible.

Comment: @FredCollins good point, that would not work then. Actually, a section footer would work for such cases, wouldn't it?

Comment: Probably not Till. Btw I solved my problem in a nice way. Checkout the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to subscribe to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.  Those notifications contain the exact parameters of the keyboard animation.

The long answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704371/77567.

Regarding your tab bar: the answer I linked assumes you want to slide your view down to the bottom edge of the screen when the keyboard is dismissed.  Since you want to slide it down  to the edge of the tab bar, you need to look at whether the keyboard is hiding or showing (by checking `note.name`).  If it's showing, you should save the current frame of the view in an instance variable.  If it's hiding, you should set the view's new frame to that frame you saved in an instance variable, instead of setting it based on the keyboard's end frame.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The code works well when the keyboard will show and the field slide up, but it doesn't when the keyboard will hide and the field slide down. In a specific way, when the field slide down, it slides at `origin.y = 363` and it will hide by the `UITabBar` (with 49 height). How exactly does the `CGRect keyboardFrameForTextField = [self.commentView.superview convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];`? Do you know how to fix with the tabbar?