# Resize a view when a keyboard appears (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, landscape-portrait

I realize there are many similar solutions, such as [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding), [Apple's famous solution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), and various suggestions involving the use of UIScrollView. In my case, I need to resize a view to accommodate the keyboard rather than scroll or move it. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704137/keeping-object-on-top-of-keyboard-in-the-event-of-becomefirstresponder-or-resign/8704371#8704371) comes closest to what I'm trying to achieve, so it was my basis. However I'm having an issue making things work in landscape mode. My method that resizes the view when the keyboard appears is this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[self textField].superview convertRect:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] fromView:nil];
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[self textField].superview convertRect:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame fromView:nil];

    CGRect bounds = [self textField].superview.bounds;    
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, bounds.size.width, keyboardFrame.origin.y + statusBarFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        [self textField].superview.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

This works perfectly in portrait mode.

[image]

However, in landscape mode, the view resizes from left-to-right or right-to-left depending upon in which direction the device was rotated, rather than from the bottom up.

[image]

Clearly there is something wrong with how I'm using coordinates, and some frame of reference isn't what I think it is when in landscape mode, but I'm having a heck of a time sorting out how to resolve it. I've tried converting all kinds of things with -convertRect: but nothing I'm trying is getting me anywhere.

I'm really hoping someone who's less confused by all these rectangles and how they change when orientation changes can spot what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to get this right. For reference, I've [created a project](https://github.com/bkocik/KeyboardResize) showing the simplest case that reproduces the problem I'm having.

Comment: You want to turn the iPan when the keyboard is visible?

Comment: Ideally, yes, since I'm sure some users will do that. But I think if I can get this solution to work (I'm adding a method when the keyboard is hidden to resize the view back up again) that'll work automatically. I believe when a device is rotated with the keyboard showing, iOS sends the keyboardWillHide and keyboardWillShow notifications in succession.

Comment: Thanks for the animation code, very handy.

Comment: The use of `curve` here is not correct actually. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957476/ios-7-keyboard-animation/18975862

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do not advise you to resize root view for your view controller, you can create contentView and add to view of view controller. You can change size of this contentView as below (I don't use autolayouting):

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd fromView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve animations:^{
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, keyboardFrameEnd.size.width, keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was resizing my root view my only problem? (Other than not removing myself as observer on dealloc and not having the code to run when hiding the keyboard; I have those in the actual app.)

Comment: Now the application is very simple therefore difficult to talk about any more problems:). In the future possible problems you can always solve here.

Comment: The code in both notification handlers is identical so one method instead of two could be used.

Answer (score 8):

Vitaliy B's answer in swift. I got a view called templateHeaderContentView, I created a function and configured the view height there. You use your own view and change the height accordingly there.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardShowOrHide(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardShowOrHide(notification)
}

private func keyboardShowOrHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
    guard let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]else { return }
    guard let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] else { return }
    guard let keyboardFrameEnd = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] else { return }

    let curveOption = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve.integerValue << 16))
    let keyboardFrameEndRectFromView = view.convertRect(keyboardFrameEnd.CGRectValue, fromView: nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration.doubleValue ?? 1.0,
        delay: 0,
        options: [curveOption, .BeginFromCurrentState],
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.templateHeaderContentView.configureView(keyboardFrameEndRectFromView.origin.y)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I used Vitaily's answer, but consider including the configureView function for the posterity ;)

Answer (score 2):

Covered very well straight form the horses mouth:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Have you tried that solution? It doesn't work. I mentioned that in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

i had done it hope this code will be helpfull for u.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveControls:notification up:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveControls:notification up:NO];
}

- (void)moveControls:(NSNotification*)notification up:(BOOL)up
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect newFrame = [self getNewControlsFrame:userInfo up:up];

    [self animateControls:userInfo withFrame:newFrame];
}

- (CGRect)getNewControlsFrame:(NSDictionary*)userInfo up:(BOOL)up
{
    CGRect kbFrame = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbFrame = [self.view convertRect:kbFrame fromView:nil];

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += kbFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1);

    return newFrame;
}

- (void)animateControls:(NSDictionary*)userInfo withFrame:(CGRect)newFrame
{
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:animationOptionsWithCurve(animationCurve)
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = newFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}

static inline UIViewAnimationOptions animationOptionsWithCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve curve)
{
    return (UIViewAnimationOptions)curve << 16;
}
```

Comment: Great effort, but this answer was answered two years ago. To make better use for your skills you may want to look trough the list of recent questions on your tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone?sort=newest&pageSize=30

Answer (score -1):

Try this methods. Edit it according to your requirement.

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 280.0

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self setViewMoveUp:NO];
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif{
    [self setViewMoveUp:YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    stayup = YES;
    [self setViewMoveUp:YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    stayup = NO;
    [self setViewMoveUp:NO];
}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMoveUp:(BOOL)moveUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (moveUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard 
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.

        if (rect.origin.y == 0 ) {
            rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            //rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if (stayup == NO) {
            rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            //rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        }
    }
    self.view.frame = rect; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this moves the view - I need to resize mine - and by a hard-coded value; I prefer to find the size of they keyboard at runtime for future-proofing.