# UITableViewCell cell is the keyboard cover

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

When `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` is called cell is covered by the keyboard, I want when cell location above the keyboard when `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` is called. How can I do this?

Similar to the iphone SMS function!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize a view when a keyboard appears (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043371/resize-a-view-when-a-keyboard-appears-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to show your textfield which in bottom of tableview by changing tableview "Y" coordinate

```
        #pragma mark - textfield delegate

        - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender {
                   activeTextField = sender;

                   if ([sender isEqual:TextField1]) {
                      [self setViewMovedForViewIndex:1];
                   }
                   else if ([sender isEqual:TextView2])
                   {
                      [self setViewMovedForViewIndex:2];
                   }

        }

      - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
        {
                 [textField resignFirstResponder];
                 [self setViewMovedForViewIndex:0];
                 return YES;
        }

    - (void)setViewMovedForViewIndex:(int)index {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // if you want to slide up the view

        CGRect rect = self.table.frame; 

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                rect.origin.y = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                rect.origin.y = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                rect.origin.y = -160;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        self.table.frame = rect;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for `KeyboardAccessory` view. You can achieve this. Look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-text-input-view--mobile-15661). It will help. And try to study about it.

Apple has [a sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html) for this.