# UITextField as child of it's own inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar

I'm attempting to duplicate a UI similar to Messages. I have a UIToolbar pinned to the bottom of the view in a xib. On that toolbar is a UITextField. I've set the UITextField's input AccessoryView to be the UIToolbar. When I click on the UITextField, it snaps into position, but there's no keyboard underneath, just blank as if the keyboard was hidden. When I click on the UITextField a second time it animates with the keyboard. I've attempted to become it's delegate and all the other suggestions in other SO posts, but no luck.

```
@implementation ChatViewController {
  IBOutlet UIToolbar *_keyboardAccessory;
  IBOutlet UITextField *_textField;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_textField setInputAccessoryView:_keyboardAccessory];
}
```

Comment: try _textField.inputAccessoryView = _keyboardAccessory;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be simpler if you don't try to make the toolbar be the text field's `inputAccessoryView`.  Just animate the toolbar up with the keyboard appears, and down when it disappears.

Everything you need to know to do this animation is documented in [“Managing the Keyboard” in the *Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/cc8a92/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1).  You can also find answers on stack overflow describing the process.  [here is an answer describing the process step-by-step with all the code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704371/77567)