# UITextView as inputAccessoryView like iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, toolbar

I want to have the same kind of behaviour as iMessage has for its input. I don't know in what end I should start, so I'll describe what I want to do and you can (I hope) give me suggestions on how to do this. I code in Swift so I'd like it to be in Swift if you provide any code.

### What I want

I want to have a button on my screen (not an `UITextView` or `UITextField`) which upon press shows the keyboard, and where the keyboard has a `UIToolBar` with an `UITextView` in it. When I type in the `UITextView` the ToolBar/TextView expands up until a certain point then it starts to scroll.

How on earth do I do this? I've been trying for an hour but I can't seem to trigger the keyboard unless I have a `UITextView` or `UITextField` to set as `becomeFirstResponder()`. Furthermore I don't understand how I'm supposed to attach a `UITextView` to the `UIToolBar` once I get the keyboard up. I have added the `UIToolBar`, but not the `UITextField`.

Cheers

Comment: a good start could be a search on google about it, there are also people that made control like that available on git. For instance https://github.com/muukii/NextGrowingTextView?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_79

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108162/make-uitextview-parent-be-its-own-inputaccessoryview?s=7|1.6466

Comment: I fixed this problem with childViewController. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219487/1836420).

Answer (score -1):

This should do it for you: https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALTextInputBar

It grows like you mentioned, and it's also at the bottom of screen, like an input accessory view.

1. In your pods file copy paste

   ```
   pod 'ALTextInputBar'
   ```
2. Run your podfile
3. Configure it like this

   ```
   import ALTextInputBar

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       let textInputBar = ALTextInputBar()

       // The magic sauce
       // This is how we attach the input bar to the keyboard
       override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
           get {
               return textInputBar
           }
       }

       // Another ingredient in the magic sauce
       override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
           return true
       }
   }
   ```