# ScrollView not animating up with keyboard ios

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have got a View containing Table View with a search bar. Under the table view I have a scroll view with collection view inside it. I've used the exactly the same code as given [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/08/animate-around-ios-keyboard/). I also followed a similar question of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099318/animate-uiview-up-with-keyboard). But the scrollView does not animate with keyboard. I've made an IBOutlet of scrollView and used it to get the frame and newFrame as for the tutorial. Is it because that subViews cannot be animates like that?

My code link : http://pastebin.com/mWdAkrDV

Comment: download https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding and use class that is automatically scroll when keyboard OPEN.

Comment: Thanks for mention but I want to do it without library, programatically.