# iOS UIScrollView scrolling down when popping/pushing (UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification interactively triggered)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I have a `UIScrollView` which I've taught to automatically adjust `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` to avoid the Keyboard.

I have achieved this by listening to the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification, and automatically inset the `UIScrollView` by the Keyboard Frame's height.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)registerKeyboardListener
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                             object:nil];
}

static inline UIViewAnimationOptions animationOptionsWithCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve curve)
{
  // UIViewAnimationCurve #7 is used for keyboard and therefore private - so we can't use switch/case here.
  // source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327374/5281431
  RCTAssert(UIViewAnimationCurveLinear << 16 == UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear, @"Unexpected implementation of UIViewAnimationCurve");
  return curve << 16;
}

- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  if (![self automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets]) {
    return;
  }
  if ([self isHorizontal:_scrollView]) {
    return;
  }

  double duration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  UIViewAnimationCurve curve = (UIViewAnimationCurve)[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
  CGRect beginFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  CGRect endFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

  CGPoint absoluteViewOrigin = [self convertPoint:self.bounds.origin toView:nil];
  CGFloat scrollViewLowerY = self.inverted ? absoluteViewOrigin.y : absoluteViewOrigin.y + self.bounds.size.height;

  UIEdgeInsets newEdgeInsets = _scrollView.contentInset;
  CGFloat inset = MAX(scrollViewLowerY - endFrame.origin.y, 0);
  if (self.inverted) {
    newEdgeInsets.top = inset;
  } else {
    newEdgeInsets.bottom = inset;
  }

  CGPoint newContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
  CGFloat contentDiff = endFrame.origin.y - beginFrame.origin.y;
  if (self.inverted) {
    newContentOffset.y += contentDiff;
  } else {
    newContentOffset.y -= contentDiff;
  }

  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                        delay:0.0
                      options:animationOptionsWithCurve(curve)
                   animations:^{
    self->_scrollView.contentInset = newEdgeInsets;
    self->_scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = newEdgeInsets;
    [self scrollToOffset:newContentOffset animated:NO];
  } completion:nil];
}
```

> Full source code: [RCTScrollView.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4bc8ce8eac70e28c933dcf7f3d1ff76a89f6523e/React/Views/ScrollView/RCTScrollView.m#L278-L342)

While this works perfectly fine when the Keyboard shows/hides, I'm experiencing a bit weird behaviour while navigating.

When the user navigates to a new page or pops the current page, my `keyboardWillChangeFrame` notification is called with a Keyboard `.origin.y` of exactly the screen height, in other words - the keyboard is fully dismissed.

This is a problem for two reasons:

1. My `inputAccessoryView` also belongs to the Keyboard
2. The Keyboard (and the `inputAccessoryView`) don't actually dismiss, so the `keyboardWillChangeFrame` notification seems to be fired incorrectly.

This looks really weird as everything seems to move when you navigate to a new page or pop the current one, and it gets even worse when you try to interactively dismiss the page via the pop gesture.

Here's a Demo Video of how that looks:

[image: Demo GIF of bug]

> Full-res 60FPS version: [Here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15199031/116081675-d6920400-a69a-11eb-94fb-bae34bc9a8d5.MP4)

What really baffles me about all this, is that the `keyboardWillChangeFrame` function is only called **once**, and the `UIScrollView` animates that change interactively. Surely there must be a property to disable this?

Does anyone know why that's happening and how I can avoid it?

> Link to the GitHub PR/discussion with more context: [facebook/react-native #31402](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/31402#issuecomment-826795818)